# Diophantine Equations of the form $ax^3+by^3+cz^3=dxyz$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{N}$ be constant positive integers such that $d^3 > abc$. Consider the Diophantine Equation of the form:
$$ax^3+by^3+cz^3=dxyz \quad (x,y,z \in \mathbb{N})$$
Is there any known way to prove the non-existance of solutions for any $(a,b,c,d)$ if there are no modular restrictions $\big[$i.e. $\forall$ $n \in \mathbb{N}$ ; $\exists$ $(x,y,z)$ s.t. $ax^3+by^3+cz^3 \equiv dxyz \pmod{n}$$\big]$?

Comment: A seminal paper related to this subject is Selmer, Ernst S. The diophantine equation $ax ^3 + by^3 + cz^3 =0$. Acta Math. 85 (1951), 203--362.

Answer (score 1):

You can find some results about in Diophantine Equations of the great L.J.Mordell, Academic Press London and New York (1969). For example.

► $(7a+1)x^3+7b+2)y^3+(7c+4)z^3+(7d+1)xyz=0$ whit $(x,y,z)=1$ has only the trivial solution.

►Let $a,b,c$ be square-free integers, relatively prime in pairs, $abc\ne0$. Then the curve $$ax^3+by^3+cz^3+dxyz=0$$ when at most one of $a,b,c$ is $\pm1$, has either none or an infinity of rational points.

►There are other results in relation with the field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-3})$.

Comment: For the second point, can $d$ be a negative integer? And if we find one solution, do we find all solutions or just infinitely many solutions? Can these solutions be characterized?

Comment: You have details in page 78 of Mordell's book. It is not posible to characterized all the solutions because its are given by the method of tangents proper to elliptic curves.  For your question about negative, yes, if you want positive in RHS you put negative in LHS and reciprocally. Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Above equation shown below:

$ax^3+by^3+cz^3=dxyz$   -----$(1)$

Equation $(1)$ has numerical solution given below:

$(x,y,z)=(23,17,7)$

$(a,b,c,d)=(1,1,30,10)$

Above is arrived from the identity given by

"J. Sylvester" & is shown below after some modification,

$x=(f^2g+g^2h+h^2f-3fgh)$

$y=(fg^2+gh^2+hf^2-3fgh)$

$z=(f^2+g^2+h^2-fg-fh-gh)$

$(a,b,c,d)=[(1),(1),(fgh),(f+g+h)]$

For, $(f,g,h)=(5,3,2)$ we get the numerical solution,

shown above for equation $(1)$.

Sylvester's Identity can be seen on "Tito Piezas"

website "Collection of Algebraic Identities" in

the third power section.

Comment: @Haran. "OP" has a new request in his comment. In his original question he requested positive integer solution. Since, now he is looking for 'd' negative, he can take (f,g,h)=(2,3,-7) in the above parametric solution. Which produces the numerical solution (a,b,c,d)=(1,1,-42,-2) & (x,y,z)=(263,173,91). Since the algebraic solution is parametric, an infinite number of numerical solution's are possible. If "OP' is looking for "all" numerical solution's than he need's a general solution which is hard to come by for many equations.